# Google Chrome formats h1 Tag way to small

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, cross-browser

I got an issue with chrome.
A h1 Tag is formatted smaller than in IE and FF. 
Here 2 screenshots: 
[image]

[image]

I don't have a clue why is that. Do you have?
Sorry, but I don't want to post the URL here because it shouldn't be indexed by google. But it's e. g. like
ssd[minus]vergleichen.de/ssds/technische-daten/881/ocz-vector-128gb-2,5-Zoll.html
(Just C+P it and replace [minus] with -).

edit: This is the code:

```
#producttitlecontent {
padding: 6px;
margin: 2px;
background: #FDE5CA;
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

#producttitlecontent h1 {
text-align: center;
color: #686868;
padding: 4px;
font-size: 1.7em Verdana;
}


<div id="producttitlecontent">
                       <img src="../images/bkbtn.png" alt="Zur&uuml;ck"    onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">
                        <h1 itemprop="name">OCZ Vector 128GB 2,5"(VTR1-25SAT3-128G) </h1>
           </div>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with Chrome and everything to do with your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

The user agent (Chrome) built-in style sheet looks like this:

```
any(article,aside,nav,section) h1 {
font-size: 1.17em;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
}
```

So the **section** tags that you are placing it in causes this. Is there anyway you can avoid use the section tag? I know this isn't ideal but I'm just explaining what is happening.

If you move the **h1** tag outside of the section tags, it appears in a larger size (I tried it).

Answer (score 1):

Im gonna agree with @j08691 who commented on your original post and follow up with the mention of `inherited` values. It is very much likely the case on your body or your containing element, or even at a document level somewhere you have defined a `font-size` on a "master" element, and due to your use of em (but not limited to.) every layer within the main element will base its font size off the parent element it comes in, so 1.7em on the outside is smaller on the inside and smaller inside that and smaller inside that and the values keep inheriting based on its parents calculated size.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it myself I think. The solution was so easy I don't even dare to post it. I wrote

```
font-size: 1.7em Verdana;
```

facepalm! Thank you all for watching this anyway